# open a link (URL) in telegram bot automatically in python

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot. my problem is, I want to:

1. send a message to user
2. and next, open a link **automatically**

the first step is OK, but I can't do the second step.
first of all, Can I do such thing???
if is there a possibility, how can I do it?

for your information:

- I use python 3.6
- Linux Ubuntu
- python-telegram-bot

any ideas?!

thank you

Comment: What to you mean "open a link automatically"? You want it to open the link for the user on their screen? I doubt this can be done (I don't deal with telegram but with discord, although they seem similar), just send them the url, they can click on the link in your message. Otherwise, if you're opening this url to pull info from the respone use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: thanks, i think requesting might solve my problem at this point... but i have to check it first.